# In WordPress, JQuery works only when I'm logged in

Tags: jquery, wordpress

I'm working on a WordPress project and I've realised that jQuery (hence Bootstrap) works only when I'm logged in! How that can be explained/fixed?

Here's my enqueue code in case somethig is wrong here:

```
function includejs_scripts(){

    wp_deregister_script('jquery'); 

    wp_enqueue_script('jquery', get_template_directory_uri().'/js/jquery.js','',1.0,true);

    add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'jquery');

    wp_enqueue_script('bootstrap', get_template_directory_uri().'/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js','',1.0,true);

    add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'bootstrap');
}



 add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'includejs_scripts');

function loadjs(){

    wp_register_script('customjs', get_template_directory_uri().'/js/all.js', 
        '', 1.0, true);
    wp_enqueue_script('customjs');

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to enqueue jquery.js file like that. Just add dependency of jquery in your custom script enqueue code.  If you create a script that depends on "jquery" you should add it to the dependency list so WordPress knows which files to load first.

```
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'loadjs');
function loadjs(){
    wp_register_script('customjs', get_template_directory_uri().'/js/all.js', 
    array('jquery'), 1.0, true);
    wp_enqueue_script('customjs');
}
```

Comment: Please vote the answer up if this answer helps you. :)

Comment: Well it still does not work. It's true that I don't need to enqueue (or deregister!) jquery but things are a little bit strange: 1stly bootsrap doen't work no matter what, 2nd if I exclude the bootstrap enqueue jquery doensn't work(???) even if I have it in the dependency array exactly as you did...I'm so confused.

Comment: add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'loadjs'); 

    function loadjs(){

        //if I comment out the bootstrap enqueue jQuery doen't work!

        // wp_enqueue_script( 'bootstrap', get_template_directory_uri() . '/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js',
        //  array('jquery'), '',1.0, true );

        wp_register_script('customjs', get_template_directory_uri().'/js/all.js', 
            array('jquery'),'', 1.0, true);
        wp_enqueue_script('customjs');
    }

Comment: You don't need to add jquery dependency while enqueuing bootstrap.